# Mule XSLT not compiling

Tags: xslt, mule

I'm using Mule 3.3.1 CE.

I can't get an XSLT Transformer to work if the XSL is located externally in a file.

The following configuration works--it compiles and produces the expected one-line output.

```
<mulexml:xslt-transformer maxIdleTransformers="2" maxActiveTransformers="5" outputEncoding="UTF-8">
    <mulexml:xslt-text>
        <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
            <xsl:output method="xml"/>
            <xsl:template match="/">
                <xsl:element name="pocRequest"/>
            </xsl:template>
        </xsl:stylesheet>
    </mulexml:xslt-text>                
</mulexml:xslt-transformer>
```

If I take the same XSL and move it out to a file Test.xsl that is in the classpath, the file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:element name="pocRequest"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The Mule configuration now looks like:

```
<mulexml:xslt-transformer maxIdleTransformers="2" maxActiveTransformers="5" outputEncoding="UTF-8"
    xsl-file="Test.xsl"/>
```

The result is an exception that it cannot compile the stylesheet:

```
javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException: Failed to compile stylesheet. 1 error detected.
    at net.sf.saxon.PreparedStylesheet.prepare(PreparedStylesheet.java:153)
    at net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl.newTemplates(TransformerFactoryImpl.java:137)
    at net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl.newTransformer(TransformerFactoryImpl.java:88)
    at org.mule.module.xml.transformer.XsltTransformer$PooledXsltTransformerFactory.makeObject(XsltTransformer.java:363)
    at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool.addObject(GenericObjectPool.java:1615)
    at org.mule.module.xml.transformer.XsltTransformer.initialise(XsltTransformer.java:138)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.initialise(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:79)
    at org.mule.api.processor.MessageProcessors$LifecyleAwareMessageProcessorWrapper.initialise(MessageProcessors.java:62)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.initialise(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:79)
    at org.mule.api.processor.MessageProcessors$LifecyleAwareMessageProcessorWrapper.initialise(MessageProcessors.java:62)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.initialise(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:79)
    at org.mule.routing.MessageProcessorFilterPair.initialise(MessageProcessorFilterPair.java:93)
    at org.mule.routing.AbstractSelectiveRouter.initialise(AbstractSelectiveRouter.java:94)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.initialise(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:79)
    at org.mule.construct.AbstractFlowConstruct.initialiseIfInitialisable(AbstractFlowConstruct.java:309)
    at org.mule.construct.AbstractPipeline.doInitialise(AbstractPipeline.java:202)
    at org.mule.construct.AbstractFlowConstruct$1.onTransition(AbstractFlowConstruct.java:111)
    at org.mule.construct.AbstractFlowConstruct$1.onTransition(AbstractFlowConstruct.java:105)
    at org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager.invokePhase(AbstractLifecycleManager.java:141)
    at org.mule.construct.FlowConstructLifecycleManager.fireInitialisePhase(FlowConstructLifecycleManager.java:81)
    at org.mule.construct.AbstractFlowConstruct.initialise(AbstractFlowConstruct.java:104)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeCustomInitMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1581)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1522)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
    at org.mule.config.spring.SpringRegistry.doInitialise(SpringRegistry.java:89)
    at org.mule.registry.AbstractRegistry.initialise(AbstractRegistry.java:109)
    at org.mule.config.spring.SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.createSpringRegistry(SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.java:116)
    at org.mule.config.spring.SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.doConfigure(SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.java:73)
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractConfigurationBuilder.java:46)
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.java:78)
    at org.mule.config.builders.AutoConfigurationBuilder.autoConfigure(AutoConfigurationBuilder.java:101)
    at org.mule.config.builders.AutoConfigurationBuilder.doConfigure(AutoConfigurationBuilder.java:57)
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractConfigurationBuilder.java:46)
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.java:78)
    at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory.createMuleContext(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:80)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication.init(DefaultMuleApplication.java:208)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.application.ApplicationWrapper.init(ApplicationWrapper.java:64)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultMuleDeployer.deploy(DefaultMuleDeployer.java:46)
    at org.mule.tooling.server.application.ApplicationDeployer.run(ApplicationDeployer.java:56)
    at org.mule.tooling.server.application.ApplicationDeployer.main(ApplicationDeployer.java:88)
```

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: The XSL on it's own seems to compile fine. So you might need to look outside of that for your error.

Comment: Yes, I tested that first thing.

Comment: I didn't see that you specified that so that is why I made the comment. Though that also means that unless there is some issue with the couple lines in your question related to mule, that there probably isn't enough information for anyone to troubleshoot this further. This is just an observation though since I don't know anything about mule.

Comment: It looks like you're right on that front.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Your first problem is that you're not seeing the real error message that tells you what's wrong with the stylesheet. The exception stack trace only tells you that there are errors, it doesn't tell you what they are. I don't know Mule, but the stack trace shows that it's invoking Saxon underneath. Saxon will have written the error messages to System.err; you need to find some way of either ensuring that you see what's in System.err, or redirecting the errors somewhere else. I can't tell you how to achieve either without knowing anything about Mule.

There's nothing obviously wrong with the stylesheet, so my guess is that the code you're compiling isn't what you think it is. Fixing the first problem (so that you can see the error messages) will help you on your way to fixing the second.

Comment: Okay.  I'll try to find where Mule is dumping the results of the parsing.

Answer (score 0):

Your code as it is did compile fine on my machine..`Mule3.3.2` and `Java 1.6_37`. Is there anything in the flow before that's failing it. Try to isolate your flow just to `xslt-transformer` and see if it helps

Comment: I did have it pared down to just that statement in the flow.  I wonder if it's a difference between 3.3.1 and 3.3.2.

Comment: We're also on 3.3.1 but couple of things were not working as expected. There are bugs in 3.3.1. Try 3.3.2 and as I said it did worked on my machine

Comment: Thanks Lerner.  When I can get the group to switch, I will.  For now, I guess I'll work around it.